# Why the scheduleAtFixedRate - scheduleWithFixedDelay methods do not use Callable<V>

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I am doing some experiments about concurrency in Java 8

In the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) API

I can see the two following signatures:

```
schedule(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

One for `Callable` and one for `Runnable`

I can see in the API the two following too:

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

My question is, why do not exists the two equivalents for `Callable`

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(Callable<V> callable, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
scheduleWithFixedDelay(Callable<V> callable, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

I would need retrieve a boolean result for an operation.

Thank You.

Comment: Because they are being scheduled by library code, not your code? How exactly would you retrieve the results?  Would you expect the library to queue up results until you had a chance to retrieve them?

Comment: Both methods return **ScheduledFuture** which extends from **Future**. Therefore later using the "get" method I can retrieve the result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What would you expect the return type of `scheduleAtFixedRate(Callable<V>)` to be? The return type of `schedule(Callable<V>)` is `Future<V>`, indicating that at some point in the future, the value of type `V` returned by the callable will be available. You can wait for this value to be available by calling `get()` on the Future.

The return type of `scheduleAtFixedRate(Callable<V>)` cannot be something like `Future<List<V>>`, as this would mean that at some point in the future, *all* values returned by the repeated calls to the callable are available. However, there will always be more executions of the callable scheduled, so this list will never exist.

What you need for something like this is the concept of an asynchronous stream of results to which you can subscribe in such a way that you handle each result as it arrives. As far as I know, this doesn't exist in the standard library. One third-party library I know of that contains such a thing is Netflix's [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava). Using for example a [`ReplaySubject`](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) from that library, you can create the stream of results and handle each result as it is returned:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import rx.subjects.ReplaySubject;

public class Callables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example Callable that returns a boolean result
        Random random = new Random();
        Callable<Boolean> callable = () -> random.nextBoolean();

        // Turn the Callable into a Runnable that adds the last result to the stream of results
        ReplaySubject<Boolean> results = ReplaySubject.create();
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            try {
                boolean result = callable.call();
                results.onNext(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Needed since Callable can throw an exception, but Runnable cannot
            }
        };

        // Periodically run the Runnable
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Handling the results as they arrive
        results.forEach(result -> System.out.println("Result: " + result));

        System.out.println("Waiting for results...");
    }

}
```

If you decide to look at using RxJava, it may be worth using more of their API instead of using an Executor directly. You can use [`Observable.interval`](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#interval(long%2C%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to generate a stream that emits a number periodically, then map this to call your callable. This way you get the same stream of results in a more concise way:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import rx.Observable;

public class MoreCallables {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Observable<Long> periodic = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Random random = new Random();
        Observable<Boolean> results = periodic.map(i -> random.nextBoolean());

        results.forEach(result -> System.out.println("Result: " + result));

        System.out.println("Waiting for results...");
        System.in.read();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

following to the @andersschuller solution the more concise form of it may look like:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .map((Long i) -> "tick " + i)
    .forEach(result -> System.out.println("Result: " + result));
```